# Nested ObservableCollection - Propogate notification from child to parent

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I'm developing a **WPF** application with **MVVM Light Toolkit**. I just want to  display a nested `Observablecollection` which hold the Employee Attendance details into a `DataGrid` and do some CRUD functionality in the inner grid and based on those changes I have to automatically recalculate the Outer collection record. The inner collection (`PunchDetailModels`) is showing in the `RowDetailsTemplate` of the `DataGrid`.

Here is the Models :

```
    public class AttendanceModel : ObservableObject
     {
        public const string EmpNamePropertyName = "EmpName";

        private string _empName = string.Empty;

        public string EmpName
        {
            get
            {
                return _empName;
            }
            set
            {
                Set(EmpNamePropertyName, ref _empName, value);
            }
        }

        public const string PunchDetailModelsPropertyName = "PunchDetailModels";

        private ObservableCollection<PunchDetailModel> _punchDetailModels = null;

        public ObservableCollection<PunchDetailModel> PunchDetailModels
        {
            get
            {
                return _punchDetailModels;
            }
            set
            {
                Set(PunchDetailModelsPropertyName, ref _punchDetailModels, value);
            }
        }           
        private string _inOutCount;
        public string InOutCount
        {
                get
                {
                    return PunchDetailModels != null
                        ? string.Format("{0}/{1}", PunchDetailModels.Count(i => i.PunchStatus == Enums.PunchType.CheckIn),
                            PunchDetailModels.Count(i => i.PunchStatus == Enums.PunchType.CheckOut))
                        : null;
                }
            }

        public TimeSpan? FirstCheckIn
        {
            get
            {
                if (_punchDetailModels != null)
                {
                    var firstCheckIn =
                        _punchDetailModels.OrderBy(t => t.PunchTime)
                            .FirstOrDefault(i => i.PunchStatus == Enums.PunchType.CheckIn);

                    if (firstCheckIn != null)
                        return firstCheckIn.PunchTime;
                }

                return null;
            }
        }


        public TimeSpan? LastCheckOut
        {
            get
            {
                if (_punchDetailModels != null)
                {
                    var lastCheckOut =
                        _punchDetailModels.OrderBy(t => t.PunchTime)
                            .LastOrDefault(o => o.PunchStatus == Enums.PunchType.CheckOut);
                    if (lastCheckOut != null)
                        return lastCheckOut.PunchTime;
                }

                return null;
            }
        }


        public TimeSpan? TotalInTime
        {
            get
            {
                TimeSpan totalInTime = TimeSpan.Zero;

                if (_punchDetailModels != null)
                {
                    if (!IsValidRecord()) return null;

                    for (int inTime = 0; inTime < _punchDetailModels.Count; inTime += 2)
                    {
                        totalInTime += _punchDetailModels[inTime + 1].PunchTime - _punchDetailModels[inTime].PunchTime;
                    }
                }

                return totalInTime;
            }
        }

        public TimeSpan? TotalOutTime
        {
            get
            {
                TimeSpan totalInTime = TimeSpan.Zero;

                if (_punchDetailModels != null)
                {
                    if (!IsValidRecord()) return null;

                    for (int inTime = 1; inTime < _punchDetailModels.Count - 1; inTime += 2)
                    {
                        totalInTime += _punchDetailModels[inTime + 1].PunchTime - _punchDetailModels[inTime].PunchTime;
                    }
                }

                return totalInTime;
            }
        }    
}

public class PunchDetailModel : ObservableObject
    {
        public const string PunchStatusPropertyName = "PunchStatus";

        private Enums.PunchType _punchStatus;

        public Enums.PunchType PunchStatus
        {
            get
            {
                return _punchStatus;
            }
            set
            {
                Set(PunchStatusPropertyName, ref _punchStatus, value);
            }
        }

        public const string PunchTimePropertyName = "PunchTime";

        private TimeSpan _punchTime = TimeSpan.Zero;

        public TimeSpan PunchTime
        {
            get
            {
                return _punchTime;
            }
            set
            {
                Set(PunchTimePropertyName, ref _punchTime, value);
            }
        }

    }
```

ViewModel :

```
public const string AttendanceCollectionPropertyName = "AttendanceCollection";

    private ObservableCollection<AttendanceModel> _attendanceCollection = null;
    public ObservableCollection<AttendanceModel> AttendanceCollection
    {
        get
        {
            if (_attendanceCollection == null)
            {
                _attendanceCollection = new ObservableCollection<AttendanceModel>();
                //_attendanceCollection.CollectionChanged+=_attendanceCollection_CollectionChanged;
            }
            return _attendanceCollection;
        }
        set
        {
            Set(AttendanceCollectionPropertyName, ref _attendanceCollection, value);
        }
}
```

View :
[image]

Issues I'm facing :

1) When a user **ADD** or **DELETE** a particular record from Inner DataGrid, I need to get notification in the View Model. I know it's possible by registering a collection changed event for an ObservableCollection. But how it's possible for an inner `ObservableCollection` ?

2) I need to get notifications in the viewmodel for any change in CheckIn or Checkout field in the Inner DataGrid, so that I can recalucate fields like TotalInTime, TotalOutTime etc.

How can I do this ?  I'm currently stuck with this scenario. Please suggest your valuable points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing that the `ObservableObject` class is your own implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. Now to solve your issues:

1. You should register to `CollectionChanged` event in `_punchDetailModels` and raise a `PropertyChanged` event for that variable in the handler, like so:

   ```
    public ObservableCollection<PunchDetailModel> PunchDetailModels
   {
     get
     {
       return _punchDetailModels;
     }
     set
     {
       Set(PunchDetailModelsPropertyName, ref _punchDetailModels, value);
        _punchDetailModels.CollectionChanged += handler;
     }
    }           
     private void handler(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
     {
       base.RaisePropertyChanged(PunchDetailModelsPropertyName); // If you don't have a method with such signature in ObservableObject (one that takes a string and raises PropertyChanged for it) you'll have to write it.
      }
   ```

This way the view should reload automatically when adding or removing elements from the inner collection.

1. There is no other way than to subscribe to listen to `PropertyChanged` on these fields. That's what the `View` does and that's what the `ViewModel` should do also. Like so:

   ```
    public const string AttendanceCollectionPropertyName = "AttendanceCollection";

    private ObservableCollection<AttendanceModel> _attendanceCollection = null;
    public ObservableCollection<AttendanceModel> AttendanceCollection
     {
      get
      {
       if (_attendanceCollection == null)
       {
           _attendanceCollection = new ObservableCollection<AttendanceModel>();
       }
       return _attendanceCollection;
     }
      set
     {
       Set(AttendanceCollectionPropertyName, ref _attendanceCollection, value);
       _attendanceCollection.CollectionChanged+= handler
     }
   } 

    private void handler(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
     foreach (AttendanceModel model in AttendanceCollection)
           model.PropertyChanged += somethingChanged;
     }

     // Very ineffective to subscribe to all elements every time a list changes but I leave optimization to you.
    private somethingChanged (object obj, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
      if ( args.PropertyName == "CheckIn" ) // for example
       { 
             AttendanceModel ModelToRecalculate = obj as AttendanceModel;
             // You can do anything you want on that model.
       }
    }
   ```

And of course you need to raise `PropertyChanged` with `string` argument of value `CheckIn` in the `AttendanceModel` class when You think it's necessary ( for example in the `handler` method)

**EDIT:**

To answer your comment question:

*"Come to second one - I need to recalculate the Attendance Model properties like InOutCount, TotalInTime, TotalOutTime on PunchTime field update."*

The answer is: You don't need to do anything in the `ViewModel` to "recalculate". The UI is subscribed to `PropertyChange`for `InOutCount` , `FirstCheckIn` ... and so on. It's beacause of `Binding` (it does it automatically).

So All you need to do to inform the UI that given model needs to be recalculated is call `RaisePropertyChanged("InOutCount")`, `RaisePropertyChanged("FirstCheckIn")`. 
The UI will understand that it needs to GET these properties and because you have these calcualations in property getters, it'll get recalculated.

So, I see that UI needs to be recalculated every time that the INNER list changes, so all you need to do is change the `handler` code to `CollectionChanged` for `PunchDetailModels` like this:

```
// the handler for CollectionChanged for the INNER collection (PunchDetailModels)
private void handler(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
      {
        base.RaisePropertyChanged(PunchDetailModelsPropertyName); // If you don't have a method with such signature in ObservableObject (one that takes a string and raises PropertyChanged for it) you'll have to write it.
        base.RaisePropertyChanged("InOutCount")
        base.RaisePropertyChanged("FirstCheckIn")
        base.RaisePropertyChanged("LastCheckOut")
        // and so on for all the properties that need to be refreshed
       }
```

Comment: Attendance Collection Changed Event fire only on outer collection ADD or REMOVE. It won't fire on any property change. So its not possible to raise the property changed event.

Comment: Yeah, OUTER collection doesn't fire `PropertyChanged` other than for itself. I don't see what the problem is. 
- You wanted the INNER(PunchDetailModels) collection to be refreshed, DONE in point nr 1. Just call `PropertyChanged` for that collection when it changes.
- You wanted to know when some INNER fields change. Done in point nr 2. You need to subscribe to `PropertyChanged` of every `AttendanceModel` object and respond to it.

Comment: I think I see where the confusion is.
The `ViewModel` Listens for `CollectionChanged` event on `AttendanceCollection` to SUBSCRIBE to it's `AttendanceModels` `PropertyChanged` not to RAISE it.

Comment: And you may have missed the last lines:
"And of course you need to raise PropertyChanged with string argument of value CheckIn in the AttendanceModel class when You think it's necessary ( for example in the handler method)"

I dodn't write code for this because I thought you could do it yourself. Just fire `PropertyChanged` event with appropriate arguments in the right places in the `AttendanceModel`

Comment: The first part is ok. Come to second one -  I need to recalculate the Attendance Model properties like InOutCount, TotalInTime, TotalOutTime on PunchTime field update. The PunchTime field is coming from the PunchDetailModels collection. So how should I know which AttendanceModel record has to be changed for a particular upate?

Comment: The updated handler will invoke on InnerCollection Collection Changed Event. Right? As you know it will invoke only on ADD or REMOVE. So how can I recalculate the outer collection records on inner collection property update? hope you understand my question..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47417/discussion-between-dennis-and-mikewazowsky)